# How do I change the no. Of rooms if the no. Of guest exceeds 6 guests?

Tags: c++

I am making a Hotel Check In Form in C++ , whick ask the user to insert No. of Guests ..and I have a condition i.e. Max 6 guests per room. So, if the user enter more than 6 guests the No. of Room changes to 2. Or if the user enter more than 12 guests the No. of Room changes to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
int guests = 0; 

int rooms = 0; 
count << "please enter number of guests" << endl;
cin >> guests;

while (guests >= 0) {
rooms++;
guests = guests -6; 


}
```

Comment: But , if No. of guests are more than 12 then the No. of rooms changes to 3. (i.e. Only 6 guests per room).

Comment: check again, I changed the code and i think this will work now. The while loop uses a module to check if guests / 6 = 0 , if YES, then it will add a room number and  subtract 6 from guests.

Comment: sorry that would make infinite loop, i edited it again

Comment: while (guests > 0) {
rooms++;
guests = guests -6; 
}

its working ,I have changed the condition . Thanks

Comment: glad it helped :)